# Too much space between label and form-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with bootstrap forms horizontal, and i can't discover why there is soo much space between my label and my form group, see [image: here]

this is the code i have at the moment:

```
   <div>
        <h2 class="text-center"> Table Styles </h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rows" class="control-label col-md-3">current Styles:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control" v-model="tableStyle">
                    <option v-for="(item,index) in tableStyles">
                        {{ item }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
     </div>
```

i have a form horizontal above the div, since i am working with vue it is calling a component don't worry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div>
        <h2 class="text-center"> Table Styles </h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rows" class="control-label col-md-2">current Styles:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" v-model="tableStyle">
                    <option v-for="(item,index) in tableStyles">
                        {{ item }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a snippet prepared.  It ran correctly in the snippet editor, but wrong when saved.

Your code, modified more or less like this, *was* working fine.  Look after the code block...

```
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <!-- Other stuff -->

      <div>
        <h2 class="text-center"> Table Styles ( col-xs- )</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="rows" class="control-label col-xs-3">current Styles:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <select class="form-control" v-model="tableStyle">
            <option v-for="(item,index) in tableStyles">{{ item }}</option>
          </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Other stuff -->
    </div>
  </div>
  </form
```

Bootstrap CSS for `.form-horizontal .control-label` should force the label to be right aligned regardless of the `col-` sizing.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.form-horizontal .control-label {
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
  }
```

If you used your browsers developers tools you should make sure you are seeing the above CSS when you highlight the `control-label`